# Different Type User Login HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to figure out how to make a form login with difference
like some user was admin, other is user and the other is vip
I've tried to add `else` and change the variable but it didn't work.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    var vipz = new Array();
    var vasses = new Array();

    function init() {
      vipz.push("vadmin");
      vasses.push("vadmin");
      vipz.push("vuser");
      vasses.push("vuser");
      vipz.push("velcius");
      vasses.push("vitz");

      users.push("admins");
      passes.push("admins");
      users.push("vipz");
      passes.push("vipz");
      users.push("celciuss");
      passes.push("bitzs");

      ausers.push("adminsa");
      apasses.push("adminsa");
      ausers.push("vipza");
      apasses.push("vipza");
      ausers.push("celciussa");
      apasses.push("bitzsa");



    }

    function login() {
      var ddl = document.getElementById("op");
      var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

      for (var i = 0; i < vipz.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("user").value == vipz[i]) {
          if (document.getElementById("pass").value == vasses[i]) {
            if (selectedValue == "vip") {
              alert("You have logged in");
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into " + vipz[i];
            }
          }
        }
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        if (document.getElementById("user").value == users[j]) {
          if (document.getElementById("pass").value == passes[j]) {
            if (selectedValue == "user") {
              alert("You have logged in");
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into " + users[j];
            }
          }
        }
      }

      for (var k = 0; k < users.length; k++) {
        if (document.getElementById("user").value == users[k]) {
          if (document.getElementById("pass").value == passes[k]) {
            if (selectedValue == "admin") {
              alert("You have logged in");
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into " + users[k];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init();">

  <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>User</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="user" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" id="pass" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select type="opt" id="op" name="cards">
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
            <option value="user">user</option>
            <option value="vip">vip</option>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="login();" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <p id="result"></p>
  </fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Exactly, what is the problem you're facing? Simply saying `it did n't work` does n't make much sense.

Comment: only while selecting 'vip' in combobox works(with it's id&pass)
the 'user' and 'admin' don't

Comment: You can debug your code using console given with `code inspect tool` in google chrome.

Comment: As a side remark, I hope this is only for fun. Anything like this shouldn't ever make it to a public facing website. This doesn't offer any security at all.

Comment: @LaurentS. In some training programmes, they exercise this kind of activities to make things familiar and interesting. Nothing serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the only problem is that, you've forgotten to declare all arrays.
Add all missing declarations.

```
var users = new Array();
var passes = new Array();
var ausers = new Array();
var apasses = new Array();
```

Then It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not define ausers , users ,passes, apasses array

Answer (score 0):

Added missing array declarations.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

var vipz = new Array();
var vasses = new Array();
var ausers = new Array();
var apasses = new Array();

function init(){
 vipz.push("vadmin");
 vasses.push("vadmin");
 vipz.push("vuser");
 vasses.push("vuser");
 vipz.push("velcius");
 vasses.push("vitz");
 
 users.push("admins");
 passes.push("admins");
 users.push("vipz");
 passes.push("vipz");
 users.push("celciuss");
 passes.push("bitzs");
 
 ausers.push("adminsa");
 apasses.push("adminsa");
 ausers.push("vipza");
 apasses.push("vipza");
 ausers.push("celciussa");
 apasses.push("bitzsa");
 
 
 
}

function login(){
 var ddl = document.getElementById("op");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
 
 for(var i = 0;i<vipz.length;i++){
  if(document.getElementById("user").value == vipz[i]){
   if(document.getElementById("pass").value == vasses[i]){
    if (selectedValue == "vip"){
     alert("You have logged in");
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into "+vipz[i]; 
    }
   }
  }

 }
 
 for(var j = 0;j<users.length;j++){
  if(document.getElementById("user").value == users[j]){
   if(document.getElementById("pass").value == passes[j]){
    if (selectedValue == "user"){
     alert("You have logged in");
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into "+users[j]; 
    }
   }
  }

 }
 
 for(var k = 0;k<users.length;k++){
  if(document.getElementById("user").value == users[k]){
   if(document.getElementById("pass").value == passes[k]){
    if (selectedValue == "admin"){
     alert("You have logged in");
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have logged into "+users[k]; 
    }
   }
  }

 }
 

 
 
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">

<fieldset>
<table>
<tr><td><label>User</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="user" /></td></tr>
<br>
<tr><td><label>Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" id="pass" /></td></tr>
<br>
<tr><td>
<select type="opt" id="op" name="cards">
<option value="admin"> admin </option>
<option value="user"> user </option>
<option value="vip"> vip </option>
</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="login();" /></td></tr>
<p id="result"></p>
</fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```